# PHP MYSQL security regarding delete grant

Tags: php, mysql

I am quick new to web application development, and i am developing a small application at the moment.

Just wondering is it bad practice to grant **DELETE** on an MySQL user privileges. At the moment when delete i just change one of the field in the database. say for example 'status' i just updated to '0' instead '1'. Which way is the correct way to doing it? Please give me a guide. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good idea to give your users/application only exactly the privileges it needs. If your app never ever issues `DELETE` queries, it does not need that permission; not giving it that permission reduces the risk of accidentally or maliciously losing data.

It's not usually a paramount thing, but if you can, why not? It may introduce some overhead of needing to manage the SQL permissions on top of all the other things you already have to manage though.